# Is there a way to ship the Java compiler with our program?

Tags: java, javac

We want to give our users the ability to write small Java methods that we call when our library runs. These users don't have the JDK installed and wouldn't know how to do that. But they do have Java installed and are running our Java library.

Is there a way we can ship some minimal Java compiler with our library?

Comment: The answer is most likely “yes, this is a way.” The next question you should ask is “who knows a way to do this.”

Comment: I know that you can ship some things such as jps and jcmd, but I haven't tried the compiler

Comment: Cannot you make this some kind of API Service call ?

Comment: They wouldn't know how to install the JDK, but you expect them to know how to write their own methods?

Comment: Installing the JDK takes 8 clicks.

Comment: @AntonH - we figure usually a support person on a screen share will write the code for them.

Answer (score 4):

The `javac` compiler has a programmatic interface (this is used by `jshell`, among other things) and lives in the modules `java.compiler` and `jdk.compiler` in Java 9 and later.  Express a dependency on these modules and build a runtime with `jlink`.

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate some of the executables by trial and error and I have done this for the `jps` and `jcmd` tool for process checking for my application.

I've just quickly tried this for `javac` and managed to get it compiling correctly but hopefully this isn't using some of my system variables.

You need a folder structure like

```
bin
-> javac.exe
-> jli.dll

lib
-> tools.jar
```

Place your code into the bin folder and run `javac`

Baring in mind what you will need for javac to run is operating system dependant and this was tested on Windows. You might need some extra files for other operating systems like Linux as this was one of the problems I encountered.